# Definir campo para que no permita negativos

Tags: postgresql

tengo un inconveniente en una tarea que estoy desarrollando.

El problema es el siguiente: la aplicación trata sobre una distribuidora de productos en la cual los empleados van a las diferentes tiendas y realizan los pedidos, el problema está qué, al momento de realizar varios pedidos simultáneamente disminuye el stock del producto a valores negativos, ejemplo 
Dos empleados piden un producto que tiene 10 unidades, al hacerlo al tiempo el stock se reduce en 20 dando como resultado un stock de -10 lo cual es un error.

Mi pregunta es cómo puedo actualizar de manera correcta el campo stock en la base de datos para que eso no suceda.

Comment: el campo de tu base de datos debería ser USIGNED para que no aceptes negatuivos, solo positivos

Comment: además debes agregar un CONSTRAINT para que valide que no acepte valores menores o iguales a cero

Comment: @AlfredoPaz no sabemos que base de datos esta usando, y siquiera puede hacer esas cosas.. mejor preguntarle eso antes no?

Comment: mucha razón @gbianchi

Comment: Podrias decirenos que base de datos estas usando (sql es un lenguaje, no una base de datos) y tambien como es que tu programa hace para actualizar los datos? Hay muchas formas de resolver esto y todo depende de que necesites exactamente

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, voy a intentar lo que me planteas @AlfredoPaz

Comment: @gbianchi, gracias por tu respusta, utilizo PostgreSQL

Comment: Tu pregunta, como las has planteado es demasiado amplia, lo que puedo sugerirte como comentario es que estudies el tema de la simultaneidad de las transacciones, busca un modelo en el motor en el cual una transacción impida las lecturas "sucias" por parte de alguna otra, que es algo que podría estar pasándote. En pocas palabras, la transacción A debería "bloquear" las lecturas del stock actual mientras no finalice de actualizarlo, para que si una transacción B intenta hacer lo mismo, quede a la espera a que finalice A. Fundamental que las lecturas del stock se hagan dentro de la transacción.